# Service return undefined during http Post in angular

Tags: angular

Hi dear members I have this problem which I can't access UserName property
here is my user model

```
export interface User{
    UserName:String;
    token:String;
   password:String;
}
```

and here is my post method

```
login(model:any) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl+'account/login',model).pipe
    (
      map((response:User)=>
      {
       
        console.log("Account service Login"+response.UserName);
        if(response)
        {
          localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(response));
          this.currentUserSource.next(response);
          console.log(JSON.stringify("$account service"+ response.UserName));
      
        }
      })
    )


   }
```

I can access token but username returns undefined
note: the response came from .net web API

[image: the token is just ok but username is undefined]

tried to trace the error but I couldn't find any solution

Comment: What is returned from endpoint? Is property UserName present in response - check network tab in browser. Are you sure you did not make a typo? All other fields are lowercase only UserName starts uppercase.

Comment: How does the response in your network panel look like? Also I notice: You use the `map` operator. `map` always should return soemthing, the type you want to map your response to. If you don't want to alter the response, use `tap`instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tap(data=>console.log(data))
Before to use map to check the data returned by the http..
I think that u have a bug from api..
Also try to console the username after the if condition